# java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many times (20)

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I've this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Demo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

    String url = "http://www......";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "es-ES,es;q=0.8");
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
    System.out.println("Request URL ... " + url);

    boolean redirect = false;

    // normally, 3xx is redirect
    int status = conn.getResponseCode();

    if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
        || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
        || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
            redirect = true;
        }

    System.out.println("Response Code ... " + status);

if (redirect) {
    System.out.println("Redireccionando...");
    // get redirect url from "location" header field
    String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

    // get the cookie if need, for login
    String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
    System.out.println("Galletas: " + cookies);

    // open the new connnection again
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
    conn.setFollowRedirects(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "es-ES,es;q=0.8");
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");       

    System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + newUrl);

}

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    html.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

System.out.println("URL Content... \n" + html.toString());
System.out.println("Done");

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

  }

}
```

and result is:

> Request URL ... "http://www.web1.com" 
>   Response Code ... 302
>   Redireccionando... 
>   Galletas: 07c18a1bea3520c44535aafeeea31dec07a36313;
>   path=/ 
>   Redirect to URL : "https://www.web2.com"
>   java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1635)
>   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>   at Demo2.main(Demo2.java:58)

What is the problem? I'm going crazy

Comment: You probably get into a redirect loop...

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same issue and this fix, helped me to overcome it.

before calling the `openConnection();` use the following:

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. Even I spent quite a lot amount of time to fix this issue. 
I found out that issue was coming to due following: 
When you make a call to some JSON services, sometime services might return you data in raw formats or format which may not be typical `application/json`. 
Your `.openConnection()` or `InputStreamReader` may not be able to read reponse headers and JSON data.

To fix this issue I tried following and it worked for me:

- Used `HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();` instead of
  `(HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();`
- Set allow circular redirect:
  `httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS,
  true);`
- Set following post headers which is important:

  ```
  httpPost.setHeader("charset","utf-8");
  httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
  httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  ```

Use StringEntity Read input stream with UTF-8:

```
httpresponse.getEntity().getContent(),HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
```

Here is the sample code which worked for me:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url =http://....; httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true); 
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); 
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("charset","utf-8");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
//or you can try httpPost.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
StringEntity requestBody = new StringEntity(jsonBody);
requestBody.setContentType("application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(requestBody);
HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
org.apache.http.StatusLine statusRespons = httpresponse.getStatusLine(); 
if (statusRespons.getStatusCode() > 201)
{
    errorText = statusRespons.getStatusCode() + " : " + statusRespons.toString()  + " : " +statusRespons.getReasonPhrase() ;
}
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpresponse.getEntity().getContent(),HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
String s = "";
while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) 
    jsonString.append(s);
```

Hope this helps you?

Comment: To which jar HttpClient and DefaultHttpClient belong?

Comment: You can use it from package org.apache.http.impl.client and org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;. By default it comes with Eclipse. Details can also be find here http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi.